# Error band in the legend

Tags: plotting, legending, style

I want to plot multiple data sets having error bands with legends **such that the style of error band is also reflected in the corresponding legend**. So for e.g. let's say I have the following two data sets.

```
sinData = Table[{x, Around[Sin[x], 0.1*Sin[x]]}, {x, 0.1, Pi, 0.1}];
cosData = Table[{x, Around[Cos[x], 0.1*Sin[x]]}, {x, 0.1, Pi, 0.1}];
```

Now I plot them together with error bands and legend

```
ListPlot[{sinData, cosData}, IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", 
IntervalMarkersStyle -> {Blue, Red}, Joined -> True, 
IntervalMarkersStyle -> Gray, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"sin", "cos"}], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Here the problem is the legends do not have the error band. So I have the following two questions based on this problem.

1) Is it possible to show the same plot with legends having a small rectangular band in the same style as the plot where I would have the control over the height of that small rectangular band with the legend line in the middle. So for the above example the sin curve legend should look something like below with adjustable height.

[image]

2) Also is it possible to have different types of lined shading within the error band like for e.g. the commanly used are the chequered shading, forward line shading, backward line shading etc.
Below I have shown a portion of a plot with chequered shaded error band.

[image]

then it should have the corresponding chequered shaded legend

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update 2:** We can use the (undocumented) option `"LegendItem"` for `LineLegend` as follows:

First create the desired legend glyphs:

```
legenditems = MapThread[ListLinePlot[Table[{x, Around[1, 0.5]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}], 
    IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", PlotStyle -> #, IntervalMarkersStyle -> #2, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False] &, 
  {ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}, {Blue, Red}}]
```

[image]

and use `legenditems` as the setting for the option `"LegendItem"`:

```
 ListLinePlot[{sinData, cosData}, IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", 
  IntervalMarkersStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"sinData", "cosData"}, 
   "LegendItem" -> legenditems, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 50}]]
```

[image]

You can do the same for pattern-filled bands:

```
patternedlegenditems = MapThread[ListLinePlot[Table[{x, Around[1, 0.5]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}], 
    IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", PlotStyle -> #, 
    IntervalMarkersStyle -> PatternFilling[{"Diamond", #2}, ImageScaled[1/5]], 
    AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False] &, 
  {ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}, {Blue, Red}}]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[{sinData, cosData}, IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", 
  IntervalMarkersStyle -> 
     (PatternFilling[{"Diamond", #}, ImageScaled[1/50]] & /@ {Red, Blue}), 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{"sinData", "cosData"}, 
   "LegendItem" -> patternedlegenditems, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 50}]]
```

[image]

**Update:** Use the input data `Table[{x, Around[1, 0.5]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}]` to get line legends with bands:

```
legends2 = MapThread[Labeled[
   ListPlot[Table[{x, Around[1, 0.5]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}], 
      IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", 
      PlotStyle -> #, IntervalMarkersStyle -> #2, ImageSize -> 50, 
      AspectRatio -> 1, Joined -> True, Axes -> False, 
      PlotRangeClipping -> False], #3 , Right] &,
    {ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}, {Blue, Red}, {"sinData", "cosData"}}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Use `IntervalMarkersStyle -> PatternFilling[{"Diamond", #2}, ImageScaled[1/5]]` to get

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can create the desired legend markers by resizing the plots:

```
plots = MapThread[ListPlot[#, IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", 
            PlotStyle -> #2, IntervalMarkersStyle -> #3,
            Joined -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRangeClipping -> False] &, 
           {{sinData, cosData}, ColorData[97]/@ {1, 2}, {Blue, Red}}]; 

 legends = MapThread[Labeled[Show[#, AspectRatio -> 1, 
             ImageSize -> 40, PlotRange -> All], #2, Right] &, 
         {plots, {"sinData", "cosData"}}];

 Legended[Show[plots, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All], legends]
```

[image]

Use `IntervalMarkersStyle ->PatternFilling[{"Diamond", #3}, ImageScaled[1/50]]` to get

[image]

Comment: I may have been unclear. I do not want the legend to look like the plot. The legend  always needs to be  a line legend but with a band as shown in my question.

Comment: @Hubble07, please see the update.

Comment: @kglr There seems to be a problem with the code. I think `IntervalMarkersStyle -> #3` should be `IntervalMarkersStyle -> #2` and the `,` after the first `MapThread` should be a `;`.

Comment: Thank you @Rohit. Fixed it.

Comment: @kglr Thanks a lot. But I am facing one last issue. When I use `IntervalMarkersStyle -> PatternFilling[{"Diamond", #2}, ImageScaled[1/5]]`  unlike the other case the border for the legend bands become balck. I am unable to change the black color.  Where is it getting the information for the border color? Ideally I would like it to have no border, just the pattern would suffice.

Comment: @Hubble07, I don't know why. I will update with a fix if I find a way to control the border color.